# Can DirectX cause WPF applications to render very slowly?

Tags: wpf, directx

Suppose I have a DirectX game running in full screen and a WPF application running in the background; in addition, the CPU isn't at high levels, and the game's frame rate is good (i.e., 60 FPS).
Is there anything that might cause the WPF application to render itself slowly? (i.e., at 3-5 FPS)

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation): "Rather than relying on the older GDI subsystem, WPF utilizes DirectX."

Therefore, my conclusion is that, if DirectX is busy rendering the game, and the graphic card pipelines are full, the WPF application will probably have poor performance. But admittedly I have no knowledge of the prioritization that goes on behind the scenes, but I'm guessing that a background (that is, non active) window will have less priority.

Comment: I can vouch for this. The moment I want to start up Team Fortress 2, I can give up trying to work in Visual Studio and my WPF app, because they'll either have frozen solid, or be incredibly sluggish in everything.